# Unable to correctly unmarshal/marshal dynamic XML structs in Go

Tags: xml, go, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have am xsd describing an XML schema and I am trying to write the representation of this xsd in go structures so I am able to marshal/unmarshal XML based on this schema.

Here is some go playground code I wrote to reproduce the problem I am having.

https://play.golang.org/p/ktJOsCDyLW

In the schema, the tags `video` and `web` are dynamic  (as in they can both appear under `media` more than once and have different content inside).

I attempted writing a dynamic struct along with the Unmarshaller/Marshaller interface as the example shows and I seem to be able to perform the parsing but it unmarshals/marshals the internal content incorrect ignoring the Name and URL lists, only taking one element of each.

I am uncertain what the issue is here.

Any help on the matter is appreciated

Comment: Did you get a chance to verify the answer?

Comment: Sort of. I took a look at your example and I understand it however I think this is already what I am doing and I wrote the example wrong. I need some time to go through everything but it will likely take me a bit of time. Thank you very much for the quick reply. I'll get back as soon as I am able to look into it deeper

Comment: Thanks, that's okay. However as per example you gave I have added answer for it. So you can accept answer and create new question with issue details. Please let's not mix multiple things into one Q&A.

Comment: I agree. It has been marked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your sample here https://play.golang.org/p/rbcoL0ayeb. Change your definition to following:

Series:

```
type Series struct {
   Name []Name `xml:"name"`
}
```

Website:

```
type Website struct {
   Url []Url `xml:"url"`
}
```